# How companies get a top level domain TLD? eg. .SOMETHING

Tags: dns, tld, iana, icann

There is a list of all TLD registered: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt
It includes many companies' top level domains (".microsoft", ".ferrari", ".tiffany", ".volkswagen", ".google", ".kinder"). 
How do they get it? 
Everyone is allowed to have one or is there any procedure or condition to allow a company to buy it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about Internet policy, not about programming.

Comment: Have a look at this overview: https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/about/program

Answer (score 0):

To get your own TLD, you need to submit a completed, detailed application and fee (likely around $200,000 or less) to ICANN. Then, ICANN will evaluate the application(there are many companies which can help with this process). If approved, you can proceed to launching with domain registrars.

Generally companies get there own TLD as `brand` TLD.

Comment: Fee was exactly $185,000 to ICANN but clearly not the only thing to pay...

Comment: removed the specific company name